# How to spread widgets on screen?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

Following is my sample code containing three labels and three entry fields:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.geometry("1200x700")

root.iconbitmap(r'.\autocrest.ico')
root.title('Autocrest Job Card')

root.columnconfigure(0, weight=20)

topRowFrame= Frame(root,relief="ridge", width=1000)

topRowFrame.config(bd=1, relief=tk.SUNKEN)

topRowFrame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
topRowFrame.columnconfigure(1, weight=4)
topRowFrame.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
topRowFrame.columnconfigure(3, weight=4)
topRowFrame.columnconfigure(4, weight=1)
topRowFrame.columnconfigure(5, weight=4)

topRowFrame.grid(column=0,row=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W)

bookingIdLabel=tk.Label(topRowFrame, text="Booking ID")
bookingIdLabel.grid(column=0,columnspan=2, row=0, padx=5, pady=5)

bookingIdEntry=Entry(topRowFrame)
bookingIdEntry.grid(column=2,columnspan=2, row=0, padx=5, pady=5)

noLabel=tk.Label(topRowFrame, text="No")
noLabel.grid(column=4,columnspan=2, row=0, padx=5, pady=5)

noEntry=Entry(topRowFrame)
noEntry.grid(column=6,columnspan=2, row=0, padx=5, pady=5)

dateLabel=tk.Label(topRowFrame, text="Date")
dateLabel.grid(column=8,columnspan=2, row=0, padx=5, pady=5)

dateEntry=Entry(topRowFrame)
dateEntry.grid(column=10,columnspan=2, row=0, padx=5, pady=5)


root.mainloop()
```

All of widgets in following code occupy space equal to their width only. I want to increase space between them. Columnspan and weight has no impact.

Comment: Please be more specific than "I want to increase space between them". I'm not sure what you're looking for from this description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to make widgets resizable as the screen resizes you need to use `Grid.rowconfigure(root, index=0, weight=1)`. Root is the name of window/frame, index is number of the row and weight should be set to 1. You need to copy and paste this line of code and change index for the next row or use a `for loop` like this:

```
number_of_rows = 5
for i in range(number_of_rows):
   Grid.rowconfigure(root, index=i, weight=1)
```

and apply the same for columns with `Grid.columnconfigure()`.
Once you have done that put `sticky="NSEW"` so it sticks to every side of the window and fills it.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. This resolved my issue

Answer (score 0):

> Columnspan and weight has no impact.

That is because you told `grid` to make `topRowFrame` only sticky to the left side of the window. Therefore it won't stretch to fill the whole column. Your use of `root.columnconfigure(0, weight=20)` makes the column fill the window, but the widget doesn't fill the column.

Try the value "ew" (east, west) for the `sticky` attribute if you want `topRowFrame` to be as wide as the window:

```
topRowFrame.grid(column=0,row=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="ew")
```